# iPad: app stops when screen is locked

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, screen-lock

Basically I have a problem with apps stopping when the screen is locked. I have first encountered this issue when I started using [Strava](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.strava.com%2F&ei=YeeUVb2uAszsUvqYgOAH&usg=AFQjCNHhZ5FwnLXBsZMNWguZmPEVC9lZnA&sig2=dfPR0TybBBaSRt8hhBdciA&bvm=bv.96952980,d.d24).

I would normally start recording on `Strava`, lock the screen and put the `iPad` into my backpack, after I finish the ride, I would unlock the screen just to find out that the app is not running.

I initially though that this is `Strava` specific issue, but I have since tried [Endomondo](https://www.endomondo.com/) and it exhibits exactly the same behavior.

Few details:

- If I start the recording, then lock the screen, then unlock it within the short period of time (~ 1 minute or less) - the app is still running. Which means it does not stop immediately after the screen lock
- If I don't lock the screen, but just put the `iPad` into my backpack, the screen locks automatically in 5 minutes. In this case, no matter how long I ride, the app will keep running and will be still active when I unlock the screen. This is a workaround but not prefered solution

I would like to know why does iPad stop apps after the screen lock and how do I change that behavior.

I am using `iPad mini` and `iOS 8.2`

UPDATE:

based on the comments and answers from other users, few more details:

- Location Services are enabled for these apps and set to "Always on"
- Background refresh is enabled in the system and for these apps

Comment: Your talking about a GPS tracking? Can you check Settings -> Privacy ->  Location Services and check the app? I think you might need to have the app running on the foreground then click the button to switch off the screen. I you press the home button first, the app is not active.

Comment: @Rogier, I don't press the home button. I have the app running in FG before lokcing the screen. The app is obviously granted access to Location Services too

Answer (score 1):

The worst, but working solution will be to set screen locking to 30 seconds, so that it will go to sleep faster. Looks like apple does it on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Background App Refresh is deactivated?

Go to Settings > General > Background App Refresh and check if a specific app is blocked, or if the general switch is off.

[image: Background App Refresh iPhone]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. The background refresh was alway enabled for these apps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Location Services are set to "While Using" for those apps?

Go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services and look for Strava.

[image: location services]

In my settings is set to "Always"

[image: always, while using the app, never]

Comment: No, the location services are switched to "Always"